# ODataAngularResources filter contains

Tags: javascript, angularjs, odata

I'm using library ODataAngularResources.
This library has `.filter(a, b)` method and it compare full value of variable `b`.
I can't find any capability to use `contains`. 
Generated query should be like
`serviceRoot/Airports?$filter=contains(Location/Address, 'San Francisco')`

I'm also looked to `$odata.Predicate(a, operator, b)`, but i don't really know how to implement needed functionality

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Already find a solution `.filter(new $odata.Func('contains', a, b), true)`
Works as expected :)